# I'm trying to update my div element with the value of my nameInput, isn't my code right?

Tags: javascript

I have a div element with id="firstDiv" and an input field with id="nameInput".
I am trying to get the user input (from id="nameInput") and display it in my div element. shouldn't this work?

```
document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question and/or provide more detail, specifically where and how your code sample is executed. For example, if you’re expecting that code to update the div as you type, then your code is not complete or correct.

Comment: Seeing as you probably already got an answer to your question below, just a friendly tip, unless you are inserting HTML elements, like <p>, <div> etc., use `document.getElementById("firstDiv").textContent` instead, its a better practice and a better thing to do, because `innerHTML` is exploitable. Cheers!

Comment: @Petar Can you expand upon why you believe that `innerHTML` is exploitable?

Comment: @AdamChubbuck that's what I've been told, presumably by more experienced people as I am fairly new into this (about 8 months self-learning), stating that it's very common source of client-side HTML-injection (DOM-XSS) security holes. So basically someone could change the inner HTML of that element, and instead insert a script, with its source linking to another page, thus injecting something that might be bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, that code should work. I can't be sure without seeing more context but I suspect the issue you're having is that the code runs when the page loads (before you type anything into the input element).

To test that hypothesis, add a `value='test'` attribute to your input element and I'll bet you'll see `test` appear in your div.

You'll probably want to add an event handler to your input element so that your code runs whenever the input element's value changes.

html:

```
<div id="firstDiv"></div>
<input type="text" id="nameInput" oninput="updateDivFromInput()"></input>
```

javascript:

```
function updateDivFromInput() {
  document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
}
```

Comment: the oninput worked. However, I had an onchange event instead. Why didn't it work?

Comment: onchange works too but it doesn't fire until the input loses focus (you click somewhere else for example).

Answer (score 0):

I not so sure if I understand you,

Are you trying to throw the value of "nameInput" to your div, because if you'r, first try to :

document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;

Some advice, right now, we have jquery to do this simple things and a lot others,

In Jquery, you can try:

$('#firstDiv').val('#nameInput');

Comment: I want to do this with pure JS and yes this is the code I posted but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: document.getElementById("firstDiv").value= document.getElementById("nameInput").value;

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code will work, as demonstrated below.

```js
document.getElementById("nameInput").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  document.getElementById("firstDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementById("nameInput").value;
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="nameInput" />
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Output: <span id="firstDiv"></span> </h3>
</div>
```